# Apartment on lease in two states but have always lived in one state, do I have to pay state tax in both states?

Tags: state-taxes

I live in NJ and work in NY. However, I have also leased an apartment in my name in Delaware. But I've never lived in Delaware. Do I have to pay tax for Delaware state as well?

My friend used to live in the same apartments complex in a 1Bed apartment and his wife was expecting and his parents were coming over, but the apartments management were not ready to shift them to a 2 bed apartment, so I took a 2 bed apartment on lease on my name to help my friend stay in that apartment (from Dec 27th 2018). In May 2019 I added my friend's name on to the lease and removed my name from lease in June. I've never stayed there, do I still have to pay taxes for Delaware?

Can someone please also confirm, that if I had the apartment leased on my name for the whole year and have stayed there only for a few days (10-15) whenever I go to visit my friend. Does that make me liable to pay DE state tax?

Comment: Theoretically no. But you might have to have discussions with the State of Delaware, to convince them that you _really_ don't live there. Which might be hard, as why would anyone have an appartment if he doesn't ever live there? (Don't convince me, convince them...)

Comment: @Aganju: A plausible reason is that you're providing a place for your parents or other family members.  (Or possibly your mistress/boy toy &c :-))

Comment: Have you done anything to make Delaware think you are a resident? Do you have a drivers license from DE, or registered a vehicle there, or a  voter registration card?

Comment: I do not have anything in Delaware. My driver's license and car both are registered in NJ. The only thing that I use it for at times is, if I make any expensive purchase online then get it delivered in Delaware to save on sale tax.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not a resident of Delaware and do not work in Delaware, you do not need to file or pay Delaware state income taxes, as described in more detail in the **Who Must File** section of the 2018 [Delaware Resident Individual Income Tax Return](https://revenuefiles.delaware.gov/2018/TY18_booklet_res.pdf) booklet (and the matching description in the [non-resident booklet](https://revenuefiles.delaware.gov/2018/TY18_booklet_nr.pdf).

Quoting the most relevent paragraph:

> **Who is a Resident**
>
> A resident is an individual who either:
>
> - Is domiciled in this State for any part of the taxable year; or
>     Full-Time Students with a legal residence in another state remain
>     legal residents of that state unless they exhibit intentions to make
>     Delaware their permanent residence.
> - Maintains a place of abode in this State and spends more than
>     183 days of the taxable year in this State.
>
> A domicile is the place an individual intends to be his permanent home;
>   a place to which he intends to return whenever he may be absent. An
>   individual can have only one domicile. A domicile, once established,
>   continues until the individual moves to a new location and exhibits a
>   bona fide intention of making it his or her permanent home.

Comment: Can you please also confirm, that if I had the apartment leased on my name for the whole year and have stayed there only for a few days (10-15) whenever I go to visit my friend. Do I still not have to pay DE state income tax?